# Is there a way to track a run with a map on Apple Watch 2?

Tags: applications, apple-watch, watchos

As we know, the Apple Watch 2 has GPS and provides accurate distance and cadence information when going for a run, for example, even without an iPhone. However, I'm having trouble finding a way of seeing a map of where I ran. Is there an app or way to track a run (without an iPhone) and get/save a map outline as well?

I've tried the Workout app and RunKeeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is possible. Runkeeper updated their app just after I posted this question.

Also, in the Activity app, go to the Workouts tab, tap a workout that would have been tracked with GPS and scroll down to the Route. Tapping the Route will display a map of the route.